Los dedos de los pies
En español, la palabra dedos se utiliza tanto para las manos como para los pies.
En Las Islas Canarias se habla de dedos para referirse a las manos y de ñoños para los pies.
¿Existen otros nombres locales para «los dedos del pie»?

Guau, interesante. Por acá usamos ‘dedos’ indistintamente, no tenemos voces diferentes para cada grupo.

(sugerencia: pregúntesele a ChatGPT)

@tac 22: Gracias por tu sugerencia, arrojó las siguientes posibilidades aparte de ñoños (Canarias): "garrones" (en algunas zonas de Argentina) y "patitas" (en ciertas regiones de México) pero no encuentro confirmación de esto en ninguna parte.

jajaja a mi me tiró ‘toes’, según la IA es un anglicismo que se usa coloquialmente aunque tampoco lo escuché en ningún momento. Tampoco escuché nunca ‘garrones’ por acá.

En latín, había dos palabras que significaban dedo: “digitus” y “articulus”.
En francés se han utilizado ambas palabras y se habla de “doigts” para los dedos y “orteils” para los dedos del pie.
De hecho, una gallina camina sobre los dedos de los pies; la palabra patitas podría servir para dedos de los pies.
Garrones, el extremo de la pata de los animales, por donde se cuelgan después de muertos, también podría ser una posibilidad.
Hasta ahora, solo ñoños parece utilizarse con efectividad.
Dejo la pregunta abierta por si alguien todavía aportara una respuesta.

Las preguntas son para dejarlas abiertas. A veces, una pregunta bien hecha puede ser más importante que su respuesta.

Los dedos de los pies se llaman ortejos. No es un nombre local, pero lo indico porque no ha sido mencionado.

Esta palabra sería de origen náhuatl, donde efectivamente significa «dedos del pie». Teniendo en cuenta que esta lengua aún la hablan 1,5 millones de personas en México, podría haber sido adoptada por el español local.

Por León, he oído "dedas" para referirse a los dedos de los pies, tal vez sea LLionés

Gracias. También lo mencionan la RAE (rae.es/tdhle/deda) y el Diccionario Leonés (https://www.pallabreirulliones.com/traductor/inicio?idioma=castellano).
